# Azure multistage yaml pipeline how to substitute appsetting indexed value

Tags: azure, yaml, pipeline

I have an issue relating to appsettings.json substitution in yaml variable.

app setting config

```
"Serilog": {
    "LevelSwitches": { "$controlSwitch": "Information" },
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "ControlledBy": "$controlSwitch",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "!FromSecret!",
          "apiKey": "!FromSecret!",,
          "controlLevelSwitch": "$controlSwitch"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": ""
    }
```

in yaml I need to replace !FromSecret! with actual value

```
variables:
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo.0.Args.apiKey
    value: '$(Secret-AppSettings-Serilog-ApiKey)'
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo.0.Args.serverUrl
    value: '$(Secret-API-AppSettings-Serilog-Url)'
```

the above yaml substitution is now working as unable to find the index need a help

need expert help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use below yaml script to modify ARGS object in an array element and index like below:-

```yaml
variables:
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo[0].Args.apiKey
    value: '$(Secret-AppSettings-Serilog-ApiKey)'
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo[0].Args.serverUrl
    value: '$(Secret-API-AppSettings-Serilog-Url)'
```

[image]

Complete YAML script with app settings and Azure Web app :-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appSettingsFile: 'path/to/appsettings.json'
  serverUrlVariable: '$(Secret-API-AppSettings-Serilog-Url)'
  apiKeyVariable: '$(Secret-AppSettings-Serilog-ApiKey)'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: AzureAppConfiguration@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Azure Subscription'
    action: 'SetKeyValue'
    Key: 'Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:serverUrl'
    Value: '$(serverUrlVariable)'
    AppConfigurations: 'MyAppConfig'
    AppConfigurationEnvironment: 'MyAppConfigEnvironment'

- task: AzureAppConfiguration@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My Azure Subscription'
    action: 'SetKeyValue'
    Key: 'Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:apiKey'
    Value: '$(apiKeyVariable)'
    AppConfigurations: 'MyAppConfig'
    AppConfigurationEnvironment: 'MyAppConfigEnvironment'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/appsettings.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Siddhesh, it worked for me with below syntax
`variables:
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo.0.Args.apiKey
    value: '$(Secret-AppSettings-Serilog-ApiKey)'
  - name: Serilog.WriteTo.0.Args.serverUrl
    value: '$(Secret-API-AppSettings-Serilog-Url)'`